# File Upload undefined index error php

Tags: php, file-upload

I mentioned in Code that "Error line" that position line show this error" **Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lab\register2.php on line 33** ". But in my database data increased means primary key(id). And i need solve it in PHP Please help me .

```
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{

 $fullname=$_POST["fullname"];

 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name']; //Error line
 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //Error line


 $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']); //Error line
 $ext = $info['extension'];  //Error line
 $newname = $userid.".".$ext;  //Error line

 $target = 'uploads/'.$newname;
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target); //Error line






 require_once "config.php";
 $db=get_connection();
 $sql="INSERT INTO user(Path) VALUES('$newname')";
 mysql_query($sql); 
}

?>




 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <title></title>

    <body>
        <center>
        <form action="#" method ="POST">

        Full Name : <input type="text" name="fullname"/><br/>
        Phone : <input type="number" name="phone"/><br/>
        Address :<textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="textin"></textarea><br>
        Profile Picture : <input type="file" name="file" /> <button type="submit" name="btn_upload">Upload Image</button><br/>


        <input type= "submit" name ="back" value="Back"/><br/>
        <input type= "submit" name ="next1" value="Next"/>


          </form>

      </center>
   </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: Did you just updated your question instead of asking here about the previous comment? If the form doesn't submit the file the index isn't going to exist. or I guess you could do an empty/isset check seems kind of pointless though when you could just resolve the issue... you also could turn off error reporting or suppress the error (routes I wouldn't take).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as the form element.

So you should have

```
<form action="#" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If the contents of a file are submitted with a form, the file input should be identified by the appropriate content type (e.g., "application/octet-stream")

**Source and Learn** more about [Form Elements here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

**Note :**

Remove the `#` symbol from the form element as it is not required.

**Advice :**

Do not use [w3schools](http://w3schools.com) for all your basic learning, try using 
[PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.The enctype attribute can be used only if method="post".

```
<body>
    <center>
    <form action="#" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     // Your Code
      </form>

  </center>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   //Your form Code
</form>
```

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` this will allow your form to submit file (image, pdf,office files, etc...)

**Extra Note**

in `php.ini` (in line 912)

`file_uploads=On`

[Read This Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: There are so many other tutorials out there. Also the enctype has already been mentioned in the other 2 answers and a comment..